# Unable to separate names in a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to programming.

I can't seem to separate names taken from input into a single variable other than letter by letter with `.split()`

My code looks like this:

```
num_animals = 0
all_animals = ("")
while num_animals < 4:
    animal_name = input("Enter the name of 4 animals: ")
    if animal_name.lower() == "exit":
        break
    elif animal_name.isalpha():
        print("Thats good, added!")
        num_animals += 1
        all_animals += animal_name
    elif animal_name.isalpha() == False:
        print("Hmm, that's probably not an animal.")
print("You have entered", num_animals, "animals as follows", str(all_animals)+".") #couldn't figure out how to separate the list of animals
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I'm trying to get the names of the animals at least separated. If i run the code like this the names have no spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the array is the most suited answer. If you are looking for a string-based solution, here you go:

```
num_animals = 0
all_animals = ""
delimiter = " " # we create a delimiter
while num_animals < 4:
    animal_name = input("Enter the name of 4 animals: ")
    if animal_name.lower() == "exit":
        break
    elif animal_name.isalpha():
        print("Thats good, added!")
        num_animals += 1
        all_animals += animal_name + delimiter # we add the delimiter after each entry
    elif animal_name.isalpha() == False:
        print("Hmm, that's probably not an animal.")

# oh no we have a trailing delimiter! Note that you could remove it with `all_animals.strip()`
print("You have entered", num_animals, "animals as follows", all_animals, ".")
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/repls/DarkorchidAridBits)

Comment: Ah, that's clever. Never thought to add a separate space in the loop. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to upvote and valid any helpful answer. That was a nice first question btw. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to use an [array](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/python-array)? If not, it is time to learn about it!

```
num_animals = 0
all_animals = [] # lets create an array
while num_animals < 4:
    animal_name = input("Enter the name of 4 animals: ")
    if animal_name.lower() == "exit":
        break
    elif animal_name.isalpha():
        print("Thats good, added!")
        num_animals += 1
        all_animals.append(animal_name) # lets add an animal to the array
    elif animal_name.isalpha() == False:
        print("Hmm, that's probably not an animal.")
# `join()` is use to concat items of an array
print("You have entered", num_animals, "animals as follows", ",".join(all_animals) +".")
```

[Try it Online](https://repl.it/repls/UnconsciousGullibleMainframe)

Comment: That worked great! Thank you. Haven't seen "append" yet or "join" but I'll look into those.

Comment: @Turr Array, List, etc. are the first step in the data structure world. It is a great step to achieve. Congrats. Have fun learning!